# In-app purchase modified local currency price - Android

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I have created an in-app product (non-consumable/one time purchase) and set its price using **pricing template**.
[image]

**For discount applying purpose, I am adjusting the local currency value in the template**

[image]

In API's response, I am getting the template's base currency & not the changed value in template.

Here is the response of [onskudetailsresponse](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetailsResponseListener#onskudetailsresponse)

```
{"productId":"rs","type":"inapp","price":"₹265.00","price_amount_micros":265000000,
"price_currency_code":"INR","title":"Module1","description":"Unlimited access",
"skuDetailsToken":"something-something"}
```

**How can I obtain the set value for currency?**

My merchant account I have set as INR, I haven't tested for other currencies

Comment: @Lluis Felisart Tagging the expert

Comment: click on template and linked products. Chk if your app is listed there

Comment: Yes, templates and app are linked. That is why, I get the API response with specifics as posted

Comment: Does this work only on Prod Release and not on Closed/Internal testing?

Comment: @RahulKahale did you find a solution ?